# Customize the start menu tiles without any other program

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I want to customize my Windows 10 start menu, with my own tiles. I tested already TileCreator, problem here is that it always pops up for around 0.5 seconds, before the actual program starts. Thats annoying. I guess this program also just make some entries in the registry or works with Powershell, so is it there another way to make this custom start tiles? The custom tiles should looks like the spotify icon in the picture below, without any other text.

[Example how it looks with TileCreator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfaQp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Here is a neat guide to customize the Start menu tiles for desktop apps. Office 2010 as an example: [Customize the background colour of Office 2010 tiles on the Start screen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dai/2015/04/05/customize-the-background-colour-of-office-2010-tiles-on-the-start-screen/)

It's a bit lengthly tutorial so I can't repost it here. Basically, you need to create the visualelementsmanifest.xml (per-executable) and set the background color and specify a logo image in the XML file.

Comment: But i want using full-filled tiles. Is that also possible? So that the whole tile is just a picture.